# Spring Batch End to End Test configuration not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I followed the official Spring batch guide (https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/) and successfully did the example. For the same job, I am trying to create an end to end integration test. Especially I am using only test configuration. That is in my test I am defining all the needed beans. So this should be the only configuration needed to run the job. This gives a lot of flexibility. The test fails when creating ApplicationContext. It is complaining that it cannot find the Datasource. When I run the actual application, since I am using an in-memory database spring automatically creates the data source and spring batch related tables in the database. But when I run my test it is not automatically creating the database. How can I trigger spring to do that?

In my test configuration when I added explicit data source bean configuration it created the data source but it did not create the spring batch related tables in the database.

Below is the Test code:

```
@SpringBatchTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class PersonJobTest {

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;

    @Test
    public void testPersonJob() throws Exception{

        JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob();
        assertEquals("COMPLETED", jobExecution.getExitStatus().getExitCode());
    }


    @Configuration
    @EnableBatchProcessing
    public static class JobConfig {

        @Autowired
        public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

        @Autowired
        public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

        private JdbcTemplate simpleJdbcTemplate;

        @Bean
        public FlatFileItemReader<Person> reader() {
            return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<Person>()
                    .name("personItemReader")
                    .resource(new ClassPathResource("sample-data.csv"))
                    .delimited()
                    .names(new String[]{"firstName", "lastName"})
                    .fieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Person>() {{
                        setTargetType(Person.class);
                    }})
                    .build();
        }

        @Bean
        public PersonItemProcessor processor() {
            return new PersonItemProcessor();
        }

        @Bean
        @Autowired
        public JdbcBatchItemWriter<Person> writer(DataSource dataSource) {
            return new JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder<Person>()
                    .itemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<>())
                    .sql("INSERT INTO people (first_name, last_name) VALUES (:firstName, :lastName)")
                    .dataSource(dataSource)
                    .build();
        }

        @Bean
        public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
            return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        }

        @Bean
        public JobCompletionNotificationListener getListener(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate){
            return new JobCompletionNotificationListener(jdbcTemplate);
        }

        @Bean
        public Job importUserJob(JobCompletionNotificationListener listener, Step step1) {
            return jobBuilderFactory.get("importUserJob")
                    .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                    .listener(listener)
                    .flow(step1)
                    .end()
                    .build();
        }

        @Bean
        public Step step1(JdbcBatchItemWriter<Person> writer) {
            return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                    .<Person, Person> chunk(10)
                    .reader(reader())
                    .processor(processor())
                    .writer(writer)
                    .build();
        }
    }


}
```

pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.intuit.iip.dg.dgworkflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>dg-workflow-springbatch-poc</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>dg-workflow-springbatch-poc</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

When running the test I want spring boot to auto-configure the data source and also create spring batch related tables like it does when I run the actual application.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the `@SpringBootTest` annotation for that. Moreover, you don't need to copy the job configuration inside the test. Here is a test that passes with the getting started guide:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution;
import org.springframework.batch.test.JobLauncherTestUtils;
import org.springframework.batch.test.context.SpringBatchTest;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

@SpringBatchTest
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class PersonJobTest {

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;

    @Test
    public void testPersonJob() throws Exception{
        JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob();
        assertEquals("COMPLETED", jobExecution.getExitStatus().getExitCode());
    }

}
```

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine According to this. We should NOT need to use SpringBootTest annotation. https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#endToEndTesting. What do you think?

Comment: The question was about Spring Boot: `I want spring boot to auto-configure the data source and also create spring batch related tables`, hence my answer referring to `@SpringBootTest`. The docs you linked are for the case where you use Spring Batch without Spring Boot, in which case you don't need `@SpringBootTest`.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine I'm having an issue by adding the two annotations `@SpringBatchTest` and `@SpringBootTest`. It seems like the the batch is executing twice, so Spring tries to create tables twice and as a result get a constraint violation exception. Is there a way to avoid this ?